# NPM Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near ''

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, nrwl

I am in the process of upgrading from Angular 11 to Angular 12 for a Nx repository. I have my dependencies updated in package.json as below:

```
{
  "name": "sample-ui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "nx",
    "nx": "nx",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.0.2",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "^2.0.2",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "^2.0.2",
    "@angular/animations": "^12.2.10",
    "@angular/cdk": "12.2.10",
    "@angular/common": "^12.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.2.10",
    "@angular/core": "^12.2.10",
    "@angular/forms": "^12.2.10",
    "@angular/material": "12.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.2.10",
    "@angular/router": "^12.2.10",
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^3.1.16",
    "@ngrx/component-store": "12.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "^12.0.0",
    "@nrwl/linter": "^12.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.28.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.28.2",
    "angular-oauth2-oidc": "^10.0.3",
    "cldr-data": "^36.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "date-fns": "^2.22.1",
    "guid-typescript": "^1.0.9",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.21",
    "ng-click-outside": "^7.0.1",
    "qs": "^6.10.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "shed-css": "^1.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.1102.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.2.10",
    "@angular/language-service": "^12.2.10",
    "@nrwl/angular": "^12.0.0",
    "@nrwl/cli": "^12.0.0",
    "@nrwl/cypress": "^12.0.0",
    "@nrwl/devkit": "^12.0.0",
    "@nrwl/jest": "^12.0.0",
    "@nrwl/tao": "^12.0.0",
    "@nrwl/workspace": "12.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.6.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.10",
    "@types/jest": "26.0.8",
    "@types/lodash-es": "^4.17.6",
    "@types/node": "14.14.33",
    "@types/qs": "^6.9.7",
    "codelyzer": "6.0.1",
    "cypress": "^4.1.0",
    "dotenv": "8.2.0",
    "eslint": "^7.30.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.11.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "husky": "^4.2.5",
    "jasmine-core": "3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "5.0.2",
    "jest": "26.2.2",
    "jest-preset-angular": "8.3.2",
    "karma": "5.0.9",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.5.4",
    "ng-packagr": "^11.0.0",
    "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "postcss-scss": "^2.0.0",
    "prettier": "2.2.1",
    "prettier-eslint": "^9.0.1",
    "protractor": "7.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "26.4.0",
    "ts-node": "9.1.1",
    "tslint": "6.1.3",
    "tslint-no-focused-test": "^0.5.0",
    "typescript": "4.2.3"
  }
}
```

but when I do `npm i` I am getting:

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near ''

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\svi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2023-06-17T20_09_45_898Z-debug.log
```

and here is how the log file looks like:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'i'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.8
3 info using node@v14.15.0
4 verbose npm-session 249e8354cbb6ba4e
5 silly install runPreinstallTopLevelLifecycles
6 silly preinstall XXXXXX-ui@0.0.0
7 info lifecycle XXXXXX-ui@0.0.0~preinstall: XXXXXX-ui@0.0.0
8 silly install loadCurrentTree
9 silly install readLocalPackageData
10 timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 3533ms
11 silly install loadIdealTree
12 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
13 timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 38ms
14 silly install loadShrinkwrap
15 timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadShrinkwrap Completed in 1959ms
16 silly install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree
1809 silly saveTree | | | +-- readable-stream@2.3.7
1809 silly saveTree | | | | +-- safe-buffer@5.1.2
1809 silly saveTree | | | | `-- string_decoder@1.1.1
1809 silly saveTree | | | `-- set-immediate-shim@1.0.1
1809 silly saveTree | | +-- rimraf@2.7.1
1809 silly saveTree | | +-- tmp@0.0.30
1809 silly saveTree | | `-- xml2js@0.4.23
1809 silly saveTree | |   `-- xmlbuilder@11.0.1
1809 silly saveTree | +-- source-map-support@0.4.18
1809 silly saveTree | | `-- source-map@0.5.7
1809 silly saveTree | +-- webdriver-js-extender@2.1.0
1809 silly saveTree | `-- webdriver-manager@12.1.8
1809 silly saveTree |   +-- del@2.2.2
1809 silly saveTree |   | +-- globby@5.0.0
1809 silly saveTree |   | | +-- array-union@1.0.2
1809 silly saveTree |   | | +-- arrify@1.0.1
1809 silly saveTree |   | | `-- pify@2.3.0
1809 silly saveTree |   | +-- is-path-cwd@1.0.0
1809 silly saveTree |   | +-- is-path-in-cwd@1.0.1
1809 silly saveTree |   | | `-- is-path-inside@1.0.1
1809 silly saveTree |   | +-- pify@2.3.0
1809 silly saveTree |   | `-- rimraf@2.7.1
1809 silly saveTree |   +-- ini@1.3.8
1809 silly saveTree |   +-- rimraf@2.7.1
1809 silly saveTree |   `-- semver@5.7.1
1809 silly saveTree +-- qs@6.10.1
1809 silly saveTree +-- rxjs@6.6.7
1809 silly saveTree +-- shed-css@1.4.0
1809 silly saveTree +-- ts-jest@26.4.0
1809 silly saveTree +-- ts-node@9.1.1
1809 silly saveTree +-- tslib@2.3.1
1809 silly saveTree +-- tslint-no-focused-test@0.5.0
1809 silly saveTree +-- tslint@6.1.3
1809 silly saveTree | +-- builtin-modules@1.1.1
1809 silly saveTree | +-- chalk@2.4.2
1809 silly saveTree | | +-- ansi-styles@3.2.1
1809 silly saveTree | | | `-- color-convert@1.9.3
1809 silly saveTree | | |   `-- color-name@1.1.3
1809 silly saveTree | | `-- supports-color@5.5.0
1809 silly saveTree | |   `-- has-flag@3.0.0
1809 silly saveTree | +-- mkdirp@0.5.5
1809 silly saveTree | +-- semver@5.7.1
1809 silly saveTree | +-- tslib@1.14.1
1809 silly saveTree | `-- tsutils@2.29.0
1809 silly saveTree +-- typescript@4.2.3
1809 silly saveTree +-- uuid@8.3.2
1809 silly saveTree `-- zone.js@0.11.4
1809 silly saveTree   `-- tslib@2.3.0
1810 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near ''
1810 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
1810 verbose stack     at parseJson (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\json-parse-better-errors\index.js:7:17)
1810 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\body.js:96:50
1810 verbose stack     at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
1810 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
1811 verbose cwd D:\q_repo\sample-ui
1812 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.22621
1813 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i"
1814 verbose node v14.15.0
1815 verbose npm  v6.14.8
1816 error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near ''
1817 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I am not able to figure out what is reasone for it. I feel like somewhere `zone.js -> tslib` is causing this, but I am not sure !

Comment: What version of npm are you using? To get that use `npm --version` on command line. Strongly recommend upgrading NPM.

Comment: npm version is `6.13.4` and node `v12.14.0`

Comment: Worth upgrading NPM for sure, thats quite old.

Comment: @adsy : I can but I want to be in the range of node version that is supported by Angular. So with `12.14.0` , i should be able to work with this npm version

Comment: Try running with `npm install --ignore-scripts`. Theres a strong chance its a postinstall script of some package. Also try a `npm cache clean --force`